# extending JSX css element

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

In react JSX theme I have 2 CSS  elements.

```
button1: {
        color: 'white',
        borderColor: 'green',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor:"white"
        },
        borderTopRightRadius: "18px",
        borderBottomRightRadius: "18px",
        borderTopLeftRadius: "18px",
        borderBottomLeftRadius: "18px",
        width: '180px'
}
button2: {
        color: '#7F4095',
        borderColor: '#7F4095',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor:"white"
        },      
        borderTopRightRadius: "18px",
        borderBottomRightRadius: "18px",
        borderTopLeftRadius: "18px",
        borderBottomLeftRadius: "18px",
        width: '180px'
}
```

If you see most of the properties are same. How do I make sure I have 2 elements but they reuse the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread syntax:

```
const button_proto = {
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
  borderTopRightRadius: "18px",
  borderBottomRightRadius: "18px",
  borderTopLeftRadius: "18px",
  borderBottomLeftRadius: "18px",
  width: '180px'
}

const styles = {
  button1: {
    ...button_proto,
    color: 'white',
    borderColor: 'green'
  },
  button2: {
    ...button_proto,
    color: '#7F4095',
    borderColor: '#7F4095',
  }
}
```

[Documentation for spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)